# Error java.io.FileNotFoundException, read a webpage

Tags: java, url, filenotfoundexception

I want to read a web page with multiple page, for example: page=1 until 100

```
import org.htmlcleaner.*;
...
url = http://www.webpage.com/search?id=10&page=1

for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
    WebParse thp = new WebParse(new URL(url+j));
```

Sometimes I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.webpage.com/search?id=10&page=18
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.htmlcleaner.Utils.readUrl(Utils.java:63)
    at org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner.clean(HtmlCleaner.java:373)
    at org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner.clean(HtmlCleaner.java:387)
    at <mypackage>.WebParse.<init>(WebParse.java:21)
    at <mypackage>.WebParse.runThis(WebParse.java:54)
    at <mypackage>.WebParse.main(WebParse.java:43)
```

I think this issue is caused by my network connection as when I try refreshing (rerunning) sometimes its works well.

How can I make it automatically try rerunning when this error occurs.

Comment: By the way if your url variable is with page=1 at the end you are going from page 11 to 199, skipping pages 1-10

Comment: To automatically rerun you should handle your exception somehow. Catch it.

Comment: WebParse is my class name

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add some attempts and a little delay between them?

```
    for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
        int maxretries = 3;
        int attempts = 0;
        boolean success = false;
        while (attempts < maxretries && !success) {
            attempts++;
            try {
                WebParse thp = new WebParse(new URL(url + j));
                success = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // play nice
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Solving problems with Thread.sleep is not very nice approach. It's better to check how WebParse works and why it has problem with such easy task.

Comment: @JakubHr agreed. I was just assuming from the stacktrace that what his class WebParse does (since I could not find any reference to the package "gadgetshop" on the web) is just cleaning the html that comes from a regular URLConnection. But if he can provides us more details about how it's implemented, we can avoid potential thread issues

Comment: i did from @Leo but, for same results show at least 3 times.. forexample : result "ABCD" show on line 1,11,and 21.. with foreach result i can get 10 lines. 1. ABCD 2. DEFG 3... 11. ABCD 12. DEFG ... 21. ABCD (again)

Comment: @enhaka sorry I don't get it. Would you mind to add more details about your code and about the results you're getting into your question up there in the top of the page?